# Hazelcast's IScheduledExecutorService can't serialize task

Tags: java, spring, serialization, scheduled-tasks, hazelcast

I have a `Hazelcast` in my project, which works on two members in a cluster. Simultaneously, I use Hazelcast's `IScheduledExecutorService` to schedule a task, which gets some data form DB and put it in a cache at fixed rate.

The problem is, that my task class (task for that scheduler) has some fields, that couldn't be serialized (`IScheduledExecutorService` trying to do it), such as mybatis Mappers and hazelcast's CacheManager, which get and put data from DB to cache.

I tried to use Spring's features, such as `@Autowire` on that fields and `@SpringAware` on class, but no luck.

May be there is some Hazelcast or Spring feature which I don't know? Any help would be appreciated.

my task class:

```
@Service
@SpringAware
public class MyTask implements Runnable, Serializable {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTask.class);

private static final String CACHE1 = "cache1";
private static final String CACHE2 = "cache2";
private static final String KEY1 = "key1";
private static final String KEY2 = "key2";

@Autowired
private MapperOne mapperOne;

@Autowired
private MapperTwo mapperTwo;

@Autowired
// if mark it 'transient' it would be null for other threads
private transient CacheManager cacheManager;

@Override
public void run() {
    LOG.info("ABOUT TO UPDATE CACHE");
    List<SomeStuff> stuff1 = mapperOne.getData();
    List<OtherStuff> stuff2 = mapperTwo.getData();

    cacheManager.getCache(CACHE1).put(KEY1, stuff1);
    cacheManager.getCache(CACHE2).put(KEY2, stuff2);
}
```

}

my scheduler:

```
@Service
public class MySchedulerService {

@Autowired
private MyTask myTask;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    if (hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getMembers().iterator().next().localMember()) {
        IScheduledExecutorService notificationCacheService =
            hazelcastInstance.getScheduledExecutorService("myService");
        notificationCacheService.scheduleOnKeyOwnerAtFixedRate(
            myTask, hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getLocalMember(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SpringAware is disabled by default. (See this [issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/5323) why it was disabled) You need to enable it by declaring `<hz:spring-aware />` or programmatically like [in this example](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/hazelcast-integration/springaware-annotation/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spring/springaware/AppConfig.java).